# Cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only

Tags: c#

I am attempting to export data to a excel spreadsheet and so open that Excel spreadsheet  using Visual Studio 2010 and Excel 2010 on Windows 7, but I get the following error.

'1.xls' cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only.

I have checked the file path and given Everyone full control of the file.  Here is my code.

```
        saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "(Excel Files)|*.xls";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.Stream st = new System.IO.FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName,
                                      FileMode.Create,
                                      FileAccess.Write,
                                      FileShare.None);
            this.gridEXExporter1.ExportMode = Janus.Windows.GridEX.ExportMode.AllRows;
            gridEXExporter1.Export(st);

      //////////////////////////////////////
      /////   Opening the Excel File
      /////////////////////////////////////
       Process.Start(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to close the output file before you try to open it using Excel. Call `st.Close()` before `Process.Start`.

Comment: I get this same error when I have VBA save a file I create during a VBA macro as a .csv file -- any idea why I'm getting it and how I can resolve it?

Comment: @user446667 - I'm not sure, but it sounds like it may be a different cause.  You may want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) so that you can show us the code that is failing.